# time() give wrong timestamp

Tags: php, date, time

i installed ubuntu in virtualbox, installed appache and working on web with iframes but somehow i get wrong timestamp.

first both ubuntu and host os was in same time zone so same time, but then i changed time zone for host to a different zone where is less by 1hour

So now on virtualbox ubuntu example 19:00 (webhost) and on host machine 18:00 (parent os), but if i use time() and convert to date i get 18:00 what isn't server side....

this allways 0
echo "STimeDiff=parseInt('".time()."',10)-parseInt((Date.now() / 1000 | 0));

if i convert time() to date => 2017-05-19 20:24
if i use date("Y-m-d H:i:s") => 2017-05-19 21:24

why this difference, how to fix?

Comment: Check the server time at php.ini file.

Comment: i want make a timer what show the server time indifferent what is the client timezone, but somehow with time() i get same client time not server timestamp

Answer (score 1):

Check out the top comment on http://php.net/time

> The documentation should have this info. The function time() returns always timestamp that is timezone independent (=UTC).

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("UTC"); 
echo "UTC:".time(); 
echo "<br>"; 

date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Helsinki"); 
echo "Europe/Helsinki:".time(); 
echo "<br>"; 
?>
```

Outputs (notice both are the same):

`UTC:1495738754<br>
Europe/Helsinki:1495738754<br>`

> Local time as string can be get by strftime() and local timestamp (if ever needed) by mktime().`

I found that you just want to display your server date/time to your users' clients, to do that, just use `date` instead of time.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("UTC"); 
echo "UTC:".date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
echo "<br>\n";

date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Helsinki"); 
echo "Europe/Helsinki:".date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
echo "<br>\n"; 
?>
```

Outputs:

`UTC:2017-05-25 18:55:02<br>
Europe/Helsinki:2017-05-25 21:55:02<br>`

Comment: in this case isn't must be different than bucharest timezone? and why changed automatical when i changed the host machine time if appache server machine not was changed?

Comment: The code just demonstrates that time() is the same regardless of timezone. It's always UTC time. If you want another time zone, use `date()` or `mktime`

Comment: Thank you, now I understand it's everywhere where have timestamp it is utc and changed only after date conversion, so if I want show server time from different zone in JavaScript need add date('Z') and JavaScript timezone and result is server time date.